# How to redirect permalinks without the .html extention to their .html equivalents

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have been looking everywhere for this answer.

I have a wordpress website that has many many pages. I added the `.html` extention to all my pages/posts when i transitioned over to wordpress from a static html website.

I have many posts/pages that are being shared and bookmarked etc. I am noticing that many of these are excluding the .html extention.

For example:

```
www.example1.com/sampleabc.html (is being shared as)
www.example1.com/sampleabc/
```

This obviously leads to a **404 error** and loss of link credit etc..

Is there a way using the `htaccess` file to make any permalinks that are shared or clicked on that don't have the `.html` extention get redirected to the same permalinks but INCLUDING the `.html` extention so as to avoid the 'page doesn't exist 404 error"?

I hope you understand what i mean.

Any help would be greatly appreciated..

Thanks so much..
*if someone could please elaborate on where exactly to place the code in my htaccess file.

Thanks guys.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.html [R=301,L]
```